# WebView won´t appear after User Login

Tags: flutter, flutterwebviewplugin

I built an app with Flutter where the logged in user is supposed to see a Newsfeed similar to Instagram. After logging in, the app loads a blank white screen in place of the Newsfeed. Outside of this app (in a separate app without user authentication) the code works fine. Is the webview somehow restricted to users on default? Do i have to enable WebView in another file too?

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
      ),
      home: Screen1(),
    );
  }
}

class Screen1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Screen1State createState() =>  _Screen1State();
}

class _Screen1State extends State<Screen1> {
  Completer<WebViewController> _controller = Completer<WebViewController>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: WebView(
        initialUrl: 'https://hereismyURL',
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController controller) {
          _controller.complete(controller);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

After logging in, the user is automatically sent to this screen so the Newsfeed is supposed to load directly.

Comment: You're using in a iPhone or Android device? Because, if you're using in Android, there's a chance that you don't have set users permission to allow internet connection in AndroidManifest. If you're on iOS, you maybe didn't set the io.flutter.embedded_views_preview's value to YES in the Info.plist

Comment: @FellipeMalta Yes, that solved that! Is there some sort of AutoSync for Android files within a Flutter project or are they always automatically synced?

Comment: I guess not @DeeJott, if there is something like that, I'm not aware of it